# How to resize and rotate image simulataneously using canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have to resize and rotate a image before upload, resize is to make the picture smaller, and rotate is to correct the image captured by iPhone.

Here is the code i am using, for `resize`, i am using a smaller canvas to redraw the image, for rotation, i am using canvas to do it.
the problem is that, my image only show a portion of the source image. how to show the full image?

This is the source image

[image]

This is what i got with the code: you can see the rotation was correct, but the resize is not, it clips the source image and left only part of it.
[image]

this is what i want.
[image]

```js
const img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzJQD.jpg';
img.onload = e => resize_and_rotate(img, 6);

function resize_and_rotate(img, orientation) {
  let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  // limit the image to at most 600px width or 900px height.
  let ratio = img.height / img.width;
  if (img.width > 600) {
    canvas.width = 600;
    canvas.height = canvas.width * ratio;
  } else if (img.height > 900) {
    canvas.height = 900;
    canvas.width = canvas.height / ratio;
  }

  let width = canvas.width;
  let height = canvas.height;
  /*
      For iPhone, landscape mode(with home key point to right) is the correct mode, it orientation is 1
      for portrait mode(home key point to bottom), the image will rotate right by 90 degree.
   */
  if (orientation === 6) { // rotate 90 degree.
    // swap canvas width and height.
    canvas.width = height;
    canvas.height = width;

    // move to the center of the canvas
    ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);

    // rotate the canvas to the specified degrees
    ctx.rotate(0.5 * Math.PI);

    // since the context is rotated, the image will be rotated also
    ctx.drawImage(img, -img.width / 2, -img.height / 2);

  } else if (orientation === 3) { // rotate 180 degree.
    // 180° rotate left
    ctx.translate(canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  } else if (orientation === 8) { // rotate 90 degree, counter-clockwise.
    canvas.width = height;
    canvas.height = width;

    // move to the center of the canvas
    ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);

    // rotate the canvas to the specified degrees
    ctx.rotate(-0.5 * Math.PI);

    // since the context is rotated, the image will be rotated also
    ctx.drawImage(img, -img.width / 2, -img.height / 2);
  } else {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }

  // return base64 data.
//  let base64 = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
//  return base64;
  // for SO
  document.body.append(canvas);
}
```

```css
canvas{max-height: 100vh; max-width: 100vw}
```

If i remove the following piece of code, the result was right, but it does not resize my image. seems like something wrong with the canvas size? please help.

```
 // limit the image to at most 600px width or 900px height.
        let ratio = img.height / img.width;
        if (img.width > 600) {
            canvas.width = 600;
            canvas.height = canvas.width * ratio;
        } else if (img.height > 900) {
            canvas.height = 900;
            canvas.width = canvas.height / ratio;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lies in [drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage).
You are not using enough arguments and your are not using the correct values there.

After you have done your transformations (*translate(center); rotate()*), you correctly try to inverse the translation so that the image be painted from the top-left corner as it should. However, you are using the original size of your image as *x,y* parameters instead of the destination ones.

Also, by using the 3 params version, you let *destinationWidth* and *destinationHeight* be the original size of your image, while you need the width and height of your canvas:

```
ctx.drawImage(img, -width / 2, -height / 2, width, height);
```

```js
const img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzJQD.jpg';
img.onload = e => resize_and_rotate(img, 6);

function resize_and_rotate(img, orientation) {
  let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  // limit the image to at most 600px width or 900px height.
  let ratio = img.height / img.width;
  if (img.width > 600) {
    canvas.width = 600;
    canvas.height = canvas.width * ratio;
  } else if (img.height > 900) {
    canvas.height = 900;
    canvas.width = canvas.height / ratio;
  }

  let width = canvas.width;
  let height = canvas.height;
  /*
      For iPhone, landscape mode(with home key point to right) is the correct mode, it orientation is 1
      for portrait mode(home key point to bottom), the image will rotate right by 90 degree.
   */
  if (orientation === 6) { // rotate 90 degree.
    // swap canvas width and height.
    canvas.width = height;
    canvas.height = width;

    // move to the center of the canvas
    ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);

    // rotate the canvas to the specified degrees
    ctx.rotate(0.5 * Math.PI);

    // since the context is rotated, the image will be rotated also
    ctx.drawImage(img, -width / 2, -height / 2, width, height);

  } else if (orientation === 3) { // rotate 180 degree.
    // 180° rotate left
    ctx.translate(canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  } else if (orientation === 8) { // rotate 90 degree, counter-clockwise.
    canvas.width = height;
    canvas.height = width;

    // move to the center of the canvas
    ctx.translate(height / 2, width / 2);

    // rotate the canvas to the specified degrees
    ctx.rotate(-0.5 * Math.PI);

    // since the context is rotated, the image will be rotated also
    ctx.drawImage(img, -width / 2, -height / 2, width, height);
  } else {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
  }

  // return base64 data.
//  let base64 = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
//  return base64;
  // for SO
  document.body.append(canvas);
}
```

```css
canvas{max-height: 100vh; max-width: 100vw}
```

Comment: You saved me, brother!